# join multiple tables to filter 1 table

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I have several tables with a common key in each.  Say I want to start with one of the tables, and filter it down to just the records that aren't in any of the other tables.  What is the best way to do this?

In general, I know that I want to do something like the following for 2 tables:

```
SELECT
A.col_1
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.col_1 = B.col_x
WHERE B.col_x IS NULL
```

Do I just keep using JOINs after each WHERE clause?

For the case 3 tables, I would expect to do the following, but I know that it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
A.col_1
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.col_1 = B.col_x
WHERE B.col_x IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Table_C C
ON A.col_1 = C.col_i
WHERE C.col_i IS NULL
```

What is wrong with the above query?

Answer (score 0):

I am pulling your answer out of the question and posting it here to assist future visitors.

```
SELECT
  A.col_1
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.col_1 = B.col_x
LEFT JOIN Table_C C
ON A.col_1 = C.col_i
WHERE 
(
  B.col_x IS NULL
  AND
  C.col_i IS NULL
)
```